# Not seeing any alternative option for 'Publish > Create App Packages' in my WPF application in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, windows-store

I'm planning on uploading my WPF application to the store, and I've created all the relevant packages until I got to this step:

[image]

I've got no idea how to get to this option in WPF. The whole document is about packing WPF/UWP projects and I want to upload a WPF app to the store. Is there an alternative way of doing what I want to do in WPF?

Meanwhile my WPF dialogue looks like so:

[image]

What do I do?

**Edit: I can now get to the 'create app packages wizard' but this is from my packaging project. Is this the right way of doing things or should I create the app package from the application itself?**

Comment: As I know, it is not simple like UWP. Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package

Comment: Agreed.  MS only recently allowed non-UWP apps to be published to the store.  Most likely playing catchup

Comment: Have you got any idea how I could package it to the store?

Comment: dongas90 can you give me more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need meet some pre-requirements to submit the WPF app to Microsoft Store.

**Part 1**: You should be a developer for Microsoft Store.If you are not, this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/opening-a-developer-account) describes how to register for a Windows developer account in Partner Center.

**Part 2:** Package your WPF project as a desktop bridge app before the submission.I will show you how to do it by [using Visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net#prepare-your-application)(There is no need to sign the package if package the app with Visual Studio).

1. In Visual Studio, open the solution that contains your desktop application project.
2. Add a **Windows Application Packaging Project** to your solution.
3. Set the **Target Version** of this project to any version that you want, but make sure to set the Minimum Version to Windows 10 Anniversary Update.
4. In Solution Explorer, right-click the Applications folder under the packaging project and choose Add Reference.
5. Choose your desktop application project, and then choose the OK button.
6. Build the packaging project to ensure that no errors appear. If you receive errors, open Configuration Manager and ensure that your projects target the same platform.
7. Use the Create App Packages wizard to generate an MSIX package/bundle or an .msixupload/.appxupload file (for Store publishing to the Store).

**Part 3:** Then you can sumbit in your Partner Center.You can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions) for more details.

Comment: From where do I get the create app packages wizard?

Comment: [Create an app package using the packaging wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-using-the-packaging-wizard) gives you the details about using app packages wizard.

Comment: the whole point is that I can't get to this dialogue in WPF. Have you read my question?

Comment: You need to right click the Windows Application Packaging Project which included your WPF project.

Comment: OK so but why on the docs its from the UWP app but not the packaging project?

Comment: There are other ways to package, but it is more convenient to use the way in UWP docs  for packaging.